# Cannot use namespace 'RouteComponentProps' as a type

Tags: reactjs, typescript

when i use typescript define a interface which  extends RouteComponentProp

i get some problem:

**vscode error**: [ts] 不能将命名空间“RouteComponentProps”用作类型

**console error**: Cannot use namespace 'RouteComponentProps' as a type.

- index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import  Styles from './header.less';
import { Link, withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router-dom'



interface Props extends RouteComponentProps<any>{} //it can not be work well


class Header extends React.Component<Props, States> {.....}
```

- tsconfig.json

```
  "compilerOptions": {
      "outDir": "./dist/",
      "sourceMap": true,
      "jsx": "react",
      "esModuleInterop": true,
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports":true,
      "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
      "strictNullChecks": true,
      "target": "es2016",
      "module": "ESNext",  // !important!
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "strict": true,
      "typeRoots": [
        "node_modules/@types"
    ],
  },
  "include": [
      "./src/**/*",
      "./externals.d.ts"
  ],
  "exclude": [ "node_modules" ]
}
```

- externals.d.ts

```
declare module '*.less'
declare module 'react-router-dom'
```

is there anybody can give some suggestion? THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `react-router` instead of `react-router-dom`

```
 import { RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router'
```

Comment: thanks，i works ! but ,  now there are two lines of code,can it be simpler?                                                                                        import {  withRouter, RouteComponentProps } from 'react-router'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'

Comment: `Link` is not available with `react-router`; you need to use both the imports or you can create a file to export all your needed imports and use one import in other files e.g. 
`export {RouteComponentProps, Link}` from file name as `api` then you can use both as `import {RouteComponentProps, Link} from api`